# How to update objects and fields without having information hard coded?

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql

We are asking our accounts to fill out a survey with questions Q1, Q2, Q3, etc.  The survey record is inserted into Salesforce, and we are building a trigger to update related records.
For example, objects and their fields:

ObjectA__c:

- Answer_to_1__c
- Answer_to_2__c

ObjectB__c:

- Answer_to_3__c
- Answer_to_4__c

etc.
There are about a dozen different questions which are split onto a few objects.

We decided to construct an object to be used as a mapping tool, for reasons.  Each record of Field_Mapping__c has the following fields:

- Input__c
- Salesforce_Object__c
- Salesforce_Field__c (related to the above object)

So a record of this type might have the following information:

- Input__c = 'Q3'
- Salesforce_Object__c = 'ObjectB__c'
- Salesforce_Field__c = 'Answer_to_3__c'

There is a record for each mapping we would like to accomplish.

I have an Apex function that is meant to construct get the "Output" based on the Input__c, and then let "Salesforce_Object__c.Salesforce_Field__c = Output".

```
List<Field_Mapping__c> fmList = [SELECT Input__c, Salesforce_Object__c, Salesforce_Field__c FROM Field_Mapping__c];
for(fm : fmList){
String output = getOutput(fm.Input__c);
}
```

The idea is that I create a new record of Salesforce_Object__c and populate the fields collected in the SOQL Query using the getOutput function.
Without hard coding each object and field, how can I populate the values?

I want to simulate ObjectB__c.Answer_to_3__c without actually having the object and field hard coded, only retrieved from this Mapping object.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Custom Metadata Types](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.custommetadatatypes_overview.htm&type=5) might be for you. You can create those three fields, using a text field, object lookup field, and a field lookup field. The object and field lookups even come across as dynamic sOjectType and sObjectField tokens, respectively, when using Apex. You can build [Dynamic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm) to get records from the database, [Dynamic DML](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_dml.htm) for saving or deleting records, and the [sObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) get/put methods to read/write field values. Overall, it's not terribly complicated or crazy, you just have to figure out how all the moving parts fit together.